# CompositeDisposable() in Kotlin

Tags: java, android, kotlin, retrofit

Whenever I try to run my program, it's crashing on `subscription = CompositeDisposable()`. I don't know what's the problem but when I run the same project directly importing from GitHub, it works fine and when I implement it in my own project like an activity which is called by onClickListener, it's crashing on subscription = CompositeDisposable().

I'm attaching my Kotlin class, Gradle (app) and Gradle (project). I have mixed Kotlin with Java too but everything is working perfectly fine except this Kotlin class and I have called this Kotlin class from my Java class.

This is the link of library i have imported and when solely run sample, it is running fine https://github.com/kibotu/Heart-Rate-Ometer

Kotlin class:

```
import android.Manifest
import android.annotation.SuppressLint
import android.content.pm.PackageManager
import android.os.Bundle
import android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat
import android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.util.Log
import io.reactivex.disposables.CompositeDisposable
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.heartratemeter.*
import net.kibotu.heartrateometer.HeartRateOmeter
import net.kibotu.kalmanrx.jama.Matrix
import net.kibotu.kalmanrx.jkalman.JKalman


class Heartratemeter : AppCompatActivity() {

var subscription: CompositeDisposable? = null

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.heartratemeter)

}

private fun startWithPermissionCheck() {
    if (!hasPermission(Manifest.permission.CAMERA)) {
        checkPermissions(REQUEST_CAMERA_PERMISSION, 
Manifest.permission.CAMERA)
        return
    }

    val kalman = JKalman(2, 1)

    // measurement [x]
    val m = Matrix(1, 1)

    // transitions for x, dx
    val tr = arrayOf(doubleArrayOf(1.0, 0.0), doubleArrayOf(0.0, 1.0))
    kalman.transition_matrix = Matrix(tr)

    // 1s somewhere?
    kalman.error_cov_post = kalman.error_cov_post.identity()


    val bpmUpdates = HeartRateOmeter()
            .withAverageAfterSeconds(3)
            .setFingerDetectionListener(this::onFingerChange)
            .bpmUpdates(preview)
            .subscribe({

                if (it.value == 0)
                    return@subscribe

                m.set(0, 0, it.value.toDouble())

                // state [x, dx]
                val s = kalman.Predict()

                // corrected state [x, dx]
                val c = kalman.Correct(m)

                val bpm = it.copy(value = c.get(0, 0).toInt())
                Log.v("HeartRateOmeter", "[onBpm] ${it.value} => 
${bpm.value}")
                onBpm(bpm)
            }, Throwable::printStackTrace)

    subscription?.add(bpmUpdates)
 }

 @SuppressLint("SetTextI18n")
 private fun onBpm(bpm: HeartRateOmeter.Bpm) {

    // Log.v("HeartRateOmeter", "[onBpm] $bpm")
    label.text = "$bpm bpm"
 }

 private fun onFingerChange(fingerDetected: Boolean){

    finger.text = "$fingerDetected"
 }

 // region lifecycle

 override fun onResume() {
    super.onResume()
    dispose()
    //crashing on subscription = CompositeDisposable()
    //subscription = null
    subscription = CompositeDisposable()

    startWithPermissionCheck()
 } 

 override fun onPause() {
    dispose()
    super.onPause()
 }

 private fun dispose() {
    if (subscription?.isDisposed == false)
        subscription?.dispose()
 }

 // endregion

 // region permission

companion object {
    private val REQUEST_CAMERA_PERMISSION = 123
}

private fun checkPermissions(callbackId: Int, vararg permissionsId: String) 
{

    when {
        !hasPermission(*permissionsId) -> try {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, permissionsId, 
callbackId)
        } catch (ex: Exception) {
            ex.printStackTrace()
        }
    }
}

private fun hasPermission(vararg permissionsId: String): Boolean {
    var hasPermission = true

    permissionsId.forEach { permission ->
        hasPermission = hasPermission
                && ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, permission) == 
PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
    }

    return hasPermission
}

override fun onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode: Int, permissions: 
Array<String>, grantResults: IntArray) {
    when (requestCode) {
        REQUEST_CAMERA_PERMISSION -> {
            if (grantResults.isNotEmpty() && grantResults[0] == 
PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                startWithPermissionCheck()
            }
        }
    }
}
}

// endregion
```

gradle(app)

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'
apply plugin: 'com.github.dcendents.android-maven'

android {
compileSdkVersion 27
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "net.kabuto"
    minSdkVersion 16
    targetSdkVersion 27
    versionCode 4
    versionName "4.0"

    testInstrumentationRunner 
"android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}

buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled true
        shrinkResources true
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 
'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
sourceSets {
    main.java.srcDirs += 'src/main/kotlin'
    }
compileOptions {
    sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
}
}

dependencies {
implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:15.0.0'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:15.0.0'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:15.0.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27+'
implementation 'com.android.support:customtabs:27.1.1'
implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:27+'
implementation 'com.android.support:animated-vector-drawable:27+'
implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8"
implementation 'com.github.kibotu:Heart-Rate-Ometer:-SNAPSHOT'
implementation ('com.github.kibotu:KalmanRx:1.2.1') { transitive = true }
compileOnly "com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.3.0"
compileOnly "com.squareup.retrofit2:adapter-rxjava2:2.3.0"
implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:27.1.1'
implementation 'com.android.support:support-media-compat:27.1.1'
implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.0'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso- 
core:3.0.2'


}
repositories {
mavenCentral() 
}
apply from: 'https://gist.githubusercontent.com/kibotu/994c9cc65fe623b76b76fedfac74b34b/raw/65ee52482ba65050e015f4b00d8d2fc9172a10e8/javadoc.gradle'
```

gradle(project)

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to 
all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
ext.kotlin_version = '1.2.21'

 repositories {
    google()
    jcenter()
}
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.1'
    classpath 'com.github.dcendents:android-maven-gradle-plugin:2.0'
    classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
    classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-android- 
extensions:$kotlin_version"
    // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
    // in the individual module build.gradle files
}
}

allprojects {
repositories {
    google()
    jcenter()
    maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
}
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

I'm new in Kotlin.

Comment: `CompositeDisposable`is a class from RxJava 2, which you're not adding directly into your build. I would assume it is being added transitively by `KalmanRx`. Have you tried adding a dependency on RxJava directly?

Comment: no, tell me how to do it please

Comment: @NicolásCarrasco , Please, tell me what to do because i have been stuck here for days

Comment: You can check how to add remote dependencies to you app in the [docs](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/dependencies). RxJava package is `io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxjava:2.1.13` if I'm not mistaken

Comment: yes,io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxjava:2.1.13

Comment: Thankyou, bro it just working when i add io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxjava:2.1.13 ..thankyou soo much

Answer (score 0):

Also here is a link to another post displaying the use of Retrofit and RxJava2 in kotlin

[parse JSON object using retrofit in kotlin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54676652/parse-json-object-using-retrofit-in-kotlin/58108757#58108757)

Maybe adding these libraries might help:

```
implementation 'io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxandroid:2.0.1'
implementation 'io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxjava:2.1.7'
```

or try writing it out the variable like this

```
private var compositeDisposable: CompositeDisposable = CompositeDisposable()
```