# parse JSON object using retrofit in kotlin

Tags: android, json, kotlin, retrofit

I am trying to show json data using retrofit library in kotlin

This is my Json:

```
[
  {
    "login": "mojombo",
    "id": 1,

  },
  {
    "login": "defunkt",
    "id": 2,
    }
]
```

My Main activity

```
 call.enqueue(object : Callback<UserResponse> {
        override fun onResponse(call: Call<UserResponse>, response: Response<UserResponse>) {
            Log.e("list","list")
            val countrylist = response.body()
            for (size in response.body()) {
                System.out.println(size.toString())
            }

            // var listOfMovies: List<UserResponse> = response.body()?.results!!
           // myCustomAdapter = UserListAdapter(applicationContext, listOfMovies)
          //  recyclerView.setAdapter(myCustomAdapter)
            progressBar.visibility = View.GONE
        }

        override fun onFailure(call: Call<UserResponse>?, t: Throwable?) {
            progressBar.visibility = View.GONE
            Log.e("list", t.toString())
        }
    })
```

Comment: Hi, If you print your response.body() what do you get?

Comment: If already getting the response you'd need to parse it maybe using gson and then you would be able to get the elements of your pojo and probably not looping through the response.body() as you're doing.

Comment: My bad I was writing code only yo get one item from list. and because of that I got JSON exception

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's what we have on our app

```
object GetFAQsAPI {

private val LOG_TAG = GetFAQsAPI.javaClass.simpleName

interface ThisCallback {

    fun onSuccess(getFAQs: GetFAQs)

    fun onFailure(failureMessage: String)

    fun onError(errorMessage: String)
}

/* POST */
fun postData(jo: JsonObject, callback: GetFAQsAPI.ThisCallback) {
    val call = Service.getService().get_faqs(jo)
    call.enqueue(object : Callback<JsonObject> {

        override fun onResponse(call: Call<JsonObject>, response: Response<JsonObject>) {

            //Log.e(LOG_TAG, response.body().toString());

            try {
                if (response.body()?.get("success")!!.asBoolean) {

                    val gson = GsonBuilder().setPrettyPrinting().create()
                    val getFAQs = gson.fromJson(response.body(), GetFAQs::class.java)

                    callback.onSuccess(getFAQs)

                } else {
                    Log.e(LOG_TAG, "else")

                    val error = response.body()!!.get("err").asString

                    callback.onError(error)
                }

            } catch (e: Exception) {
                Log.e(LOG_TAG, "exception" + e.localizedMessage)

                callback.onFailure(e.message!!)
            }

        }

        override fun onFailure(call: Call<JsonObject>, t: Throwable) {
            Log.e(LOG_TAG, "onFailure: " + t.message)

            callback.onFailure(t.message!!)

        }
    })

}

}
```

That's how we call it from our fragment - getFAQs is the object parsed.

```
private fun getFAQsAPI() {

    showLoading(true)

    val jo = JsonObject().apply {
        addProperty("faq_category", "admin")
    }

    GetFAQsAPI.postData(jo, object : GetFAQsAPI.ThisCallback {
        override fun onSuccess(getFAQs: GetFAQs) {
            Log.i(LOG_TAG, "onSuccess")

            showLoading(false)

            updateUI(getFAQs)
        }

        override fun onFailure(failureMessage: String) {
            Log.e(LOG_TAG, failureMessage)
        }

        override fun onError(errorMessage: String) {
            Log.e(LOG_TAG, errorMessage)
        }
    })
}
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: GetFAQs is the model class retrieved using the json2schema website.

Answer (score 2):

This an app that I build in kotlin using retrofit and rxjava in the best way possible using a test API.

Model

```
data class Post( val userID:Int, val title:String, val body: String)
```

Retrofit Package

IMyApi interface

```
interface IMyApi {

@get:GET("posts")
val posts: Observable<List<Post>>
}
```

RetrofitClient Object class

```
object RetrofitClient {


val instance: Retrofit by lazy {
    Retrofit.Builder()
        .baseUrl("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/")
        .addCallAdapterFactory(RxJava2CallAdapterFactory.create())
        .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
        .build()
 }
}
```

Adapter Package

PostAdapter class

```
  class PostAdapter(private val context: Context, private val postList: List<Post>)
                :RecyclerView.Adapter<PostViewHolder>()
            {
                override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): 
   PostViewHolder {
                    val itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context)
                        .inflate(R.layout.post_item, parent, false)
                    return PostViewHolder(itemView)
                }

                override fun getItemCount(): Int {
                    return postList.size
                }

                   override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: PostViewHolder, position: Int) 
    {
                    holder.userId.text = postList[position].userID.toString()
                    holder.title.text = postList[position].title
                    holder.body.text = StringBuilder(postList[position].body.substring(0,20))
                        .append("...").toString()
                }
            }
```

PostViewHolder class

```
class PostViewHolder(itemView: View):RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView) {

var userId = itemView.txtID
var title = itemView.txtTitle
var body = itemView.txtBody
}
```

MainActivity

```
  class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

                    private lateinit var jsonApi: IMyApi
                    private var compositeDisposable: CompositeDisposable = CompositeDisposable()

                    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
                        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
                        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

                        // Init api
                        val retrofit = RetrofitClient.instance
                        jsonApi = retrofit.create(IMyApi::class.java)


                        // View
                        recycler_posts.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this)
                        recycler_posts.setHasFixedSize(true)
                        fetchData()
                    }

                    private fun fetchData() {
                        compositeDisposable.add(jsonApi.posts
                            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                            .subscribe { posts->displayData(posts)})
                    }

                    private fun displayData(posts: List<Post>?) {
                        val adapter = PostAdapter(this, posts!!)
                        recycler_posts.adapter = adapter
                    }
                }
```

Using this as displayed above should help you solve your issue hopefully. Also when in the code you come across "recycler_posts". This is a id to the recycler added in activity_main. If you need me to include that let me know